# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.googlecode.luceneappengine.GaeDirectory

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, lucene

At this point I feel that I have done all that I am supposed to do to run [Lucene-Appengine](https://code.google.com/p/lucene-appengine/). Still I am getting the following stack trace.

As troubleshooting I have already attached and then removed both the source and the javadoc to the binary of the `luceneappengine-2.2.0.jar` in eclipse. This means I had (and then not) three jars: `luceneappengine-2.2.0.jar`, `luceneappengine-2.2.0-sources.jar` and `luceneappengine-2.2.0-javadoc.jar`. In any case it made no difference

As an aside: why am I getting NoClassDefFoundError at runtime for com.googlecode.luceneappengine.GaeDirectory when the code compiles fine?

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backed method
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.googlecode.luceneappengine.GaeDirectory
    at com.company.myproject.mypath.MyClass1.methodB(MyClass1.java:109)
    at com.company.myproject.mypath.MyClass.methodA(MyClass.java:1023)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It looks like this is an expected error. In the documentation for `GaeDirectory` it says : "If your application throws NoClassDefFoundError while using GaeDirectory in order to make it work, into your GAE web application, the modified RamUsageEstimator in a package named org.apache.lucene.util". Now, I have no idea what modification you need to do. So maybe someone else can help with that. but **apparently the error is expected**.

Comment: I never noticed that. But also I have no idea how I would modify the class. Does anyone know what I need to change?

Comment: for people who want to see the quote that shows the error was expected: http://maven-site.lucene-appengine.googlecode.com/hg/apidocs/com/googlecode/lucene/appengine/GaeDirectory.html

Comment: I think the error is because you are trying to access a forbidden resource ( most probably file system) , considering LAE has been designed for GAE this is most probably due to a mix up on the dependencies. I guess using maven to get them is out of the question?

Comment: I have never used maven and I don't know how easy it would be to incorporate maven into an existing project. On the other hand, I get them from the maven repo.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your jars are on the build path, available to a compiler, but they are not available at runtime on your server.

Add these jars to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.